# Expect script does not expand bash substitution of date command into send

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have an expect script to backup fortigate VDOM firewalls.

This works well, except the dynamic filename which is based on date output.

This is the script:

```
<!-- language: expect -->
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

##!/bin/bash
#DATE=$(date "+%Y.%m.%d")
#echo $DATE

set timeout 60
spawn ssh admin@vdom
expect "password: $"
set send_slow {1 0.05}
send -s "pass\r"
send_user "pass\r"
send -s "config global\n"
send -s "execute backup full-config tftp `date \"+%Y.%m.%d\"` ip.address\n"
send -s "exit\n"
interact
```

The results of that script, is like:
VDOM1 # execute backup full-config tftp `date "+%Y.%m.%d"` ip.address

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer to the question on IRC (credit is to Venks):

`` ` `` isn't special in tcl.
The correct way of doing it is like:

```
send -s "execute backup full-config tftp [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y.%m.%d] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\n"
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.